# How to downgrade php xdebug version

Tags: 20.04, php, xdebug

I have installed xdebug in version  v3.0.1 but it cause me problem with php7.2 and my symfony installation. I can not upgrade php version now so i need to downgrade xdebug version to previews (any of 2.*) I tried something like: `sudo apt install php-xdebug=2.9.8-7.2-vc15-nts` and some other combination but nothing works.

How to downgrade xdebug version ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also face same problem today. Here is how I solve this:

remove xdebug 3.0.1  first

```
sudo apt purge php-xdebug
sudo apt remove php-xdebug
```

Prerequisit:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-dev
```

Now clone xdebug repo and compiled:

```
git clone git://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git
git checkout xdebug_2_9
phpize
./configure --enable-xdebug
sudo make install
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now add following to your php.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Best of luck!

Comment: you need to enable the mode by running `sudo phpenmod xdebug` after you set everything

Answer (score 1):

If you're on PHP 7.1 then you have to execute the following

```
apt-get install php-all-dev
git clone --branch xdebug_2_9 --single-branch git://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git
cd xdebug
phpize7.1
./configure --enable-xdebug
make
make install
phpenmod xdebug
echo "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so" > /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```